# How to specify INFINITY (U+221E) in C++ using an escape sequence?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I specify the Unicode character INFINITY (U+221E) in C++ without directly pasting the symbol (∞) into my code file? I've tried \x221e but that results in a warning, and \u221e gives me a LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX (U+00E2).

```
QString label;
label.append(tr("HP: \u221e\n\n"));
```

Comment: `\u` isn't even a valid escape sequence in C++.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: \u isn't an escape sequence, but it is a prefix for universal character name, which unlike escape sequences can be used outside of character or string literals as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try \xE2\x88\x9E.

But to make Qt use UTF-8, it seems you'll need

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
```

Somewhere before it.

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode escape is the correct way, but something else along the path is breaking it and displaying the UTF-8 as Latin-1.

Comment: @Ben: Of course it isn't. Something else is doing the right thing and encoding it as `0xE2 0x88 0x9E`. But something *else* is doing the *wrong* thing and displaying it as Latin-1.

Answer (score 0):

That's a 16-bit Unicode character.  16-bit characters can only be expressed as a single element if you are using a wide string.

Try

```
L"HP: \x221E\n\n"
```

or

```
u"HP: \x221E\n\n"
```

What encoding are you using?  If QT is expected UTF-8, then you'll actually need a sequence of multiple bytes to encode that character.

Comment: L should prefix the literal, not postfix it

Comment: Thanks usta, just caught that myself checking the C++ syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This could be used as an alternative as well:

```
label.append(trUtf8("HP: \u221e\n\n"));
```